# Custom OEM Info (Logo, Website) On Fresh Install of Windows

Tags: windows, computer-building, oem

I'm getting into the computer refurbishing business, and would like to know how to change the OEM info for the system (Right click Start->System in Windows 10).

I saw an article on How To Geek that explains how to do it by tweaking the registry, but that is after you've already set up a computer. I want the custom info to be there as soon as they set up the computer for the first time. I assume that this means I need to edit the Windows image, but how do I go about doing so?

Any guides would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: use setupcomplete.cmd to set settings

Comment: You generalize an image.  Hopefully you apply the registry to the hive that applies to all users.

Comment: Use [sysprep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation) to customize your windows image